# Show chart at angular 6

Tags: angular6, fusioncharts

I'm following [this](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/angular/angular/your-first-chart-using-angular) tutorial to show a chaart from fusionchart at angular 6

But it only is showing this message:

```
Cannot read property 'moduleObj' of undefined
```

I've done imported in app.module.ts

```
import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular-fusioncharts';



// Import fusioncharts core in the root
import FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts/core';

// Import chart type
import Column2D from 'fusioncharts/viz/column2d'; // Column2D chart

// Import the fusion theme

import FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/es/fusioncharts.theme.fusion';
import { ChartComponent } from './chart/chart.component'
// Pass the fusioncharts library and chart modules

FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Column2D, FusionTheme);

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,  FusionChartsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, ChartComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
This is my html:
Meu html está assim:

<fusioncharts
    width="700"
    height="400" 
    type="Column2d"
    [dataSource]="dataSource">
</fusioncharts>
```

Here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fusionchart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same problem, but later found it out that stackblitz internally tries to compile the code into ES5, however in FusionCharts recent modular build, they are internally using all ES6 module syntax, hence, stackblitz is not able to run the charts, however, if you check the sample locally using Angular CLI it will work fine. Let me know if you need any assistance, I can share a sample if needed.